# Make this url rewrite easy

Tags: .htaccess

i know this sounds crazy,but i want tomake this link more user friendly.please have a look at my links to make this rewrite

my real url looks like this.

http://localhost/cproject/support/about_cproject.php
but i want to make it looks like this

http://localhost/cproject/support/about
any help much appreciated. Thank you !

```
RewriteRule ^about support/about_cproject.php [NC,L]
```

i have used above codes for make this happen.but it didnt work

Comment: This [stackoverflow thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained) might be interesting for you.

Comment: Where is the htaccess located?

Comment: it is located in my root directory